# Role Management in N2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n2cms, n2

N2 CMS has the following roles by default: Everyone, Members, Writers, Editors and Administrators.  It allows you to assign users to these roles and offers role assignments for each editable page.

Is there a way to easily create additional roles for specifying which groups of users can edit certain pages? Maybe a configuration option in the n2 section of the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Click on settings, set "show non pages in navigation" to checked. Open Users node for editing. You will see one row per line. Add your role on a new line.

Next, change web config to add your new role as editors

```
<editors dynamic="true" roles="Editors,NewRole" />
```

Comment: When I open the Users node for editing I see users grouped by letter. I am not allowed to add anything, just edit an existing user.  The roles that each user can belong to are still limited to "Everyone", "Members", "Writers", "Editors" and "Administrators".  I'm not sure what you mean by "Add your role on a new line."  Am I missing something?